# Regression with 3 variables

Tags: fitting

I'm trying to find a function starting from its values but I can't find anything related to functions with 2 variables and I don't know how to go on.

So, given this sample data, I'd like to know how to find the function `f(x,y) = z`:

```
x    y    z
1    1    4
1    3    4
2    1    4
2    3    3
3    7    4
3    3    2
```

EDIT: Based on @Bob Hanlon answer, here's what I tried:

```
data={{1,1,4},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{1,4,4},{1,5,4},{2,1,4},{2,2,3},{2,3,3},{2,4,3},{2,5,3},{2,6,4},{3,1,4},{3,2,3},{3,3,2},{3,4,2},{3,5,2},{3,6,3},{3,7,4},{4,1,4},{4,2,3},{4,3,2},{4,4,1},{4,5,1},{4,6,2},{4,7,3},{4,8,4},{5,1,4},{5,2,3},{5,3,2},{5,4,1},{5,5,0},{5,6,1},{5,7,2},{5,8,3},{5,9,4},{6,2,4},{6,3,3},{6,4,2},{6,5,1},{6,6,1},{6,7,2},{6,8,3},{6,9,4},{7,3,4},{7,4,3},{7,5,2},{7,6,2},{7,7,2},{7,8,3},{7,9,4},{8,4,4},{8,5,3},{8,6,3},{8,7,3},{8,8,3},{8,9,4},{9,5,4},{9,6,4},{9,7,4},{9,8,4},{9,9,4}};

expr=a*x+b*y+c*x*y+d*y^2+e;

f[x_,y_]=expr/.FindFit[data,expr,{a,b,c,d,e},{x,y}]//Rationalize//Simplify
```

which returns

> 4.9869 + x (4.12229*10^-16 - 5.22363*10^-17 y) - 1.04811 y + 
>    0.104811 y^2

The problem is that

```
data[[All, 3]] == f @@@ data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
```

returns

> False

and this means that there are problems with some values.

Any hints?

Comment: Presumably, the problem is not with the data but rather with the model (expr) used. The initial model was selected to match the initial data provided. With different data a different model is generally required. There are an infinite number of possible models. Ideally, the problem context should provide the basis for the form of the model used. However, generally the model will not exactly fit the data; your initial example just happened to allow an exact fit.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid inserting a model? Because in WolframAlpha I can input just the values without a model and it returns the correct function, but I can't use Wolfram because it only works with just `x` or `x,y` values while I need it to work with `x,y,z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {{1, 1, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4},
   {2, 3, 3}, {3, 7, 4}, {3, 3, 2}};

expr = a*x + b*y + c*x*y + d*y^2 + e;

f[x_, y_] = 
 expr /. FindFit[data, expr, {a, b, c, d, e}, {x, y}] // 
   Rationalize // Simplify
```

> (1/4)*(17 - 2*x*(-1 + y) - 2*y + 
>         y^2)

```
data[[All, 3]] == f @@@ data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
```

> True

For your second data set, `Interpolation` will work but does not provide a symbolic result for the function.

```
data2 = {{1, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 4}, {2, 1, 4}, {2,
     2, 3}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 3}, {2, 5, 3}, {2, 6, 4}, {3, 1, 4}, {3, 2, 
    3}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 2}, {3, 5, 2}, {3, 6, 3}, {3, 7, 4}, {4, 1, 4}, {4, 
    2, 3}, {4, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 1}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 6, 2}, {4, 7, 3}, {4, 8, 
    4}, {5, 1, 4}, {5, 2, 3}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 5, 0}, {5, 6, 1}, {5, 
    7, 2}, {5, 8, 3}, {5, 9, 4}, {6, 2, 4}, {6, 3, 3}, {6, 4, 2}, {6, 5, 
    1}, {6, 6, 1}, {6, 7, 2}, {6, 8, 3}, {6, 9, 4}, {7, 3, 4}, {7, 4, 3}, {7, 
    5, 2}, {7, 6, 2}, {7, 7, 2}, {7, 8, 3}, {7, 9, 4}, {8, 4, 4}, {8, 5, 
    3}, {8, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 3}, {8, 8, 3}, {8, 9, 4}, {9, 5, 4}, {9, 6, 4}, {9, 
    7, 4}, {9, 8, 4}, {9, 9, 4}};

f2[x_, y_] = Interpolation[
    {Most[#], Last[#]} & /@ N[data2],
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][x, y];

data2[[All, 3]] == f2 @@@ data2[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
```

> True

```
f3[x_, y_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[
  {Most[#], Last[#]} & /@ N[data2],
  {x, y}]

-2247.51 + 
 y (1845.67 + 
    y (-2098.35 + 
       y (1287.93 + 
          y (-476.386 + 
             y (111.11 + 
                y (-16.461 + 
                   y (1.50615 + (-0.0778701 + 0.0017084 y) y))))))) + 
 x (4522.17 + 
    y (-1.26886 + 
       y (-2.22796*10^-6 + 
          y (0.597224 + 
             y (-4.09083*10^-7 + 
                y (-0.0916666 + 
                   y (-3.05767*10^-9 + (0.00396825 - 
                    7.89011*10^-11 y) y)))))) + 
    x (-5172.47 + 
       y (-0.000212648 + 
          y (-0.895833 + 
             y (-9.33495*10^-8 + 
                y (0.229167 + 
                   y (-1.53433*10^-8 + (-0.0138889 + 
                    3.13116*10^-10 y) y))))) + 
       x (3199.65 + 
          y (0.597353 + 
             y (1.76751*10^-7 + 
                y (-0.305556 + 
                   y (1.47372*10^-8 + (0.0277778 - 
                    7.89954*10^-10 y) y)))) + 
          x (-1195.66 + 
             y (-0.0000489357 + 
                y (0.229167 + 
                   y (-1.76202*10^-8 + (-0.0347222 + 
                    9.92743*10^-10 y) y))) + 
             x (282.79 + 
                y (-0.0916551 + 
                   y (2.75375*10^-8 + 
                    y (0.0277778 + (-6.44078*10^-10 + 
                    1.28469*10^-11 y) y))) + 
                x (-42.7287 + 
                   y (-1.73301*10^-6 + 
                    y (-0.0138889 + (3.56941*10^-11 - 
                    3.88162*10^-11 y) y)) + 
                   x (4.023 + 
                    x (-0.218417 + 
                    x (0.00552951 - 0.000027189 x + 
                    2.01327*10^-10 y) + (-8.45925*10^-9 - 
                    4.35612*10^-11 y) y) + 
                    y (0.00396842 + (3.69313*10^-10 + 
                    5.36392*10^-11 y) y))))))))
```

The maximum absolute error for your data2 is

```
Max[Abs[data2[[All, 3]] - f3 @@@ data2[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]]
```

> 1.3827*10^-7

Comment: Unfortunately I need a symbolic result because I need to translate the given result into a `java` code.